# PHP SQL unexpected T_STRING Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line #9

This is the line that is attempting to add the column. I have double, and triple checked that the table does indeed exist - and that I am able to access it.

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost","user","pass") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

echo "connected to database!";

mysql_select_db ("database");

      $query = ALTER TABLE CustomerInformation
 ADD supplier_name varchar2(50);


      $result = mysql_query($query) 
        or die("altering table Customer Information not successful: ".
        mysql_error()); 

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your problem

```
$query = ALTER TABLE CustomerInformation ADD supplier_name varchar2(50);
```

should be changed to

```
$query = 'ALTER TABLE CustomerInformation ADD supplier_name varchar2(50)';
```

Your $query variable holds a STRING which is passed to mysql_query and used as a command.

Comment: should actually be 'ALTER TABLE CustomerInformation ADD supplier_name varchar2(50)';

Comment: !!! Awesome! Thank you so much! How can I be sure when I need to use " ' " vs quotations in PHP?

Comment: You always use quotes to enclose string values. Only functions / variables / constants / reserved words are not.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```sql
$query = ALTER TABLE CustomerInformation
 ADD supplier_name varchar2(50);
```

to

```sql
$query = 'ALTER TABLE CustomerInformation ADD supplier_name varchar2(50)';
```